# Problems with roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Well I'm following this tutorial that was suggested by my teacher to understand the work with roles [Roles](https://andersnordby.wordpress.com/2014/11/28/asp-net-mvc-4-5-owin-simple-roles-management/)

The problem is I did everything step by step right but in the last step I can’t get it working because it says: `Default parameter 'value' for context must be a compile time constant` I tried everything and I don’t know why it does not work. If someone can give a hint to solve this I would appreciate a lot.

**Home Controller**

```
using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
    var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

    roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Admin"));

    var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
    var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

    var user = userManager.FindByEmail("my.email@somewhere.com");
    userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: there's most probably a method accepting an argument which param has a default value that should be evaluated lately. It's not in the code you have pasted.

Comment: Your user variable returns the expected value? Did you insert the user before that? Try to investigate the InnerException.

Comment: the problem is somehow with the context, by the way i used @ before the using and it let me use var i think that part is done, but then i have the exception problem

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with `var context = new ApplicationDbContext()`. C# expects default values to be "compile time constants," which includes things like number and string literals, and excludes new instances of classes or returns from method calls. The simplest way I can think of to pull off what you are trying is to replace the argument with `ApplicationDbContext context = null` (null can be the default value because it is a compile time constant) and add in the line to the method body `if(context == null){ context = new ApplicationDbContext(); }`

Comment: there is another problem that says method must have a return type ahead on my using dont know why it asked for a return type :S

Comment: it just happen when i add the using... inside my homeController :S

Comment: In C# every method must declare what it returns. If it isn't supposed the return anything, the return type is `void`, and the syntax is as follows: `void myMethod(/*arguments*/) {/*body*/}`

Comment: but he calls for the return type on my method above when i put the @using statemente and cant solve it, it dont let me use it inside the homeController :S

Comment: Correct. You declare the return type in the definition, not the call. in your case, the definition (when you type the method) would look like `void @using(...` and the call (inside homeController) would look like `@using(...`.

Comment: hmmm kinda confusing its inside the home controller so as you say @using should work, but it doesnt, i tryied void using and it has no errors now

Comment: I am glad it is working. Let me rephrase what I mean by "calling" versus "defining." Your code above is a definition. A call is when, inside another method, you write `@using();`. Sorry if I confused you.

Comment: then why the call @using() didnt work inside the homeController? :S

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what error you are talking about, but if I had to guess, I would say it didn't like you calling a method with and illegal definition.